# How can I refactor these two functions to be more DRY?

Tags: python

I have the following two Python functions:

```
@classmethod
def serialize_dict(cls, d):
    values = []
    for column_name in cls().distinguishing_column_names():
        value = str(d[column_name])
        if value == 'None':
            value = ''
        values.append(value)
    return ' '.join(values)

@classmethod
def serialize_row(cls, row):
    values = []
    for column_name in cls().distinguishing_column_names():
        value = str(row.value(cls()._meta.db_table, column_name))
        if value == 'None':
            value = ''
        values.append(value)
    return ' '.join(values)
```

As you can see, the two functions are identical except for the first line of the `for` loop. Not very DRY. How could I refactor this code to take out all the repetitions, given that `row` and `d` are of different types (`dict` and a custom type of mine, respectively)?

Comment: How does `row`'s type not know its table?

Comment: It's not a database row.

Comment: Possibly a good post for CodeReview.SE if a moderator could migrate it?

Comment: It seems strange that you need to create so many throw-away instances of `cls`.  Are the attributes you are accessing really instance attributes, and is it really necessary to create all those instances?

Comment: Good point, Sven. What I'm getting out of `cls().distinguishing_column_names()` is something that should actually probably be stored in a config file somewhere. As for the `cls()._meta.db.table`, I don't see any way around that.

Comment: Better yet, merge "CodeReview.SE" into this site and stop creating so many pointless, fragmented mini-sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `if isinstance(arg, dict)` to determine whether to treat it as a row or dict, then merge the two methods together.

Comment: This may not be the very most elegant solution but it seems to be the simplest. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks -- I figured, first eliminate the method-level redundancy in a simple way, assuming refactoring the cooperating class `row` might not be an option. If you can unify the interfaces of row and dict that'd eliminate a few more lines.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just implement the relevant bits of the `dict` interface in your custom type?

So that `row[column_name]` results in the code you want?

You use the `__getitem__` special method for this.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the function that serialise the bit into two different lambda functions that can then used as parameters of a single serialisation method:

```
ds = lambda d , cls , column_name : str(d[column_name])
rs = lambda d , cls , column_name : str(d.value(cls()._meta.db_table, column_name))

def __serialize(cls, d, ser):
    values = []
    for column_name in cls().distinguishing_column_names():
        value = ser(d,cls,column_name)
        if value == 'None':
            value = ''
        values.append(value)
    return ' '.join(values)


@classmethod
def serialize_dict(cls, d):
    return __serialize(cls, d, ds)

@classmethod
def serialize_row(cls, row):
    return __serialize(cls, d, rs)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the row instance can get hold of the name of its table, add a __ getitem __ method to make it behave like the dictionary. Otherwise, wrap it with a proxy object that knows the table name.